# Playlist with QMediaPlaylist in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a problem with my Playlist written in QT.

I have my small function to load mp3 file and print the name of this song in my playlist with following code:

```
void MainWindow::on_addButton_clicked()
{
    QString files = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Files"), "QString()", tr("Audio Files (*.mp3)"));

    qDebug() << player->errorString();
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(files));
    player->setVolume(ui->volumeSlider->value());

    on_playButton_clicked();

    foreach (QString filePath, files) {
        QList<QStandardItem*> items;
        items.append(new QStandardItem(QDir(filePath).dirName()));
        items.append(new QStandardItem(filePath));
        playListModel->appendRow(items);
        playlist->addMedia(QUrl(filePath));
    }
}
```

With this code I have a problem that my playlist contains ONLY 1 letter in 1 line.
When I change QString to QStringList (which would work) I get an error:

```
error: conversion from ‘QString’ to non-scalar type ‘QStringList’ requested
     QStringList files = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Files"), "QString()", tr("Audio Files (*.mp3)"));
```

How could I change it to solve my problem? 
Also the second problem is that I get full directory name with song name and I would like to get only song name.

I'd be very glad for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use getOpenFileNames() instead getOpenFileName()